# Sqlite c# multi thread

Tags: c#, sqlite

I`m using SQLite with multi-threading,my program is working fine but I wish to make it faster. I read that SQLite has 3 threads modes 
 that can be set compile time(https://www.sqlite.org/threadsafe.html) where the default is "Serialized" but from what I read, the "Multi-thread" would be faster for me.

What I don't understand is how to set SQLite to "Multi-thread" mode in Visual Studio 2013.Anyone know how can I do this? I already found questions talking about this subject but none of them showed clearly how to set this mode.

Comment: that's up to the build of sqlite you are using

Comment: @DanielA.White is that always true though? The document OP linked says there are 3 options of selecting threading modes (compile time is #1).

Comment: @BrootsWaymb read "Assuming that the compile-time threading mode is not single-thread,"

Comment: @DanielA.White - Ah, gotcha. I guess because I assumed OP is using serialized as default that they weren't using single-thread (which might be true, who knows). You're correct, I'm assuming too much.

Comment: I thought I only had to write SQLITE_THREADSAFE=2 somewhere in the project properties. I'm using System.Data.SQLite (x86/x64)

Answer (score 0):

This is how to make sqlite work in multiple threads.

Use BlockingCollection with ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem.
Any database query are queued and executed in FIFO (First In First Out) order.
Now the database is never locked while doing any SQL transaction from any thread.
This is an example in C#.

```
public class DatabaseQueueBus
{
    private BlockingCollection<TransportBean> _dbQueueBus = new BlockingCollection<TransportBean>(new ConcurrentQueue<TransportBean>());
    private CancellationTokenSource __dbQueueBusCancelToken;

    public CancellationTokenSource _dbQueueBusCancelToken { get => __dbQueueBusCancelToken; set => __dbQueueBusCancelToken = value; }

    public DatabaseQueueBus()
    {
        _dbQueueBusCancelToken = new CancellationTokenSource();
        DatabaseQueue();

    }

    public void AddJob(TransportBean dto)
    {
        _dbQueueBus.Add(dto);
    }

    private void DatabaseQueue()
    {

        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((param) =>
        {
            try
            {
                do
                {
                    string job = "";
                    TransportBean dto = _dbQueueBus.Take(_dbQueueBusCancelToken.Token);
                    try
                    {
                        job = (string)dto.DictionaryTransBean["job"];
                        switch (job)
                        {
                            case "SaveClasse":
                                //Save to table here
                                break;
                            case "SaveRegistrant":
                                //Save Registrant here
                                break;
                          
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {//TODO: Handle this exception or not

                    }

                } while (_dbQueueBusCancelToken.Token.IsCancellationRequested != true);
            }
            catch (OperationCanceledException)
            {

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: The question is how to make Sqlite itself multi-threaded, not how to queue threads using it.